# UIView handling gestures, with inside UIButton that should catch touches

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have an UIView that contains a UIButton.
The UIView catches touch events using the following method :

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(open:)] autorelease]];
```

In some conditions, I don't want to do anything when the view is touched :

```
- (void) open:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (self.someCondition == YES) return;
    // Do very interesting stuff
}
```

The UIButton is linked to a method like this :

```
[self.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteTheWorld:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The problem is that when someCondition = YES, the UIButton does not respond to touch events. How may I make it respond ?

Note : I only display the UIButton when someCondition == YES.

Comment: Try `tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all try using `tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;` if this won't work I suggest  to use `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods to prevent touches in your views something like:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
        if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
              return YES; // button is touched then, yes accept the touch
        }
        else if (self.someContiditon == YES) {
            return NO; // we don't want to receive touch on the view because of the condition
        }
        else { 
          return YES; // tap detected on view but no condition is required
        }
  }
```

Comment: tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; worked like a charm. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to manage the button clicking in your `open` selector.

Just put something like

```
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
if(self.someCondition == YES) 
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized &&
       CGRectContainsPoint(self.deleteButton.frame, location))
         [self deleteTheWorld];
    else
         return;
```

instead of

```
- (void) open:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (self.someCondition == YES) return;
    // Do very interesting stuff
}
```

and of course you don't need to register the target action for the button then!

Comment: But I guess that doing like this, My button will just bvecome a simple rect and won't act anymore like a button, isn't it ?

Comment: yea, i you're right. i was thinking about that. i guess you already have a solution tho! By the way, i wasn't able to reproduce the problem when i tried, everything already worked fine!